# Equivariant Coefficient ring action on singular cohomology

Tags: group-actions, equivariant-cohomology

Let $X$ be a manifold acted on by a Lie group $G$. The $G$-equivariant cohomology of $X$ with coefficients in a ring $\mathcal{R}$ is defined as the cohomology ring
$$
H_G^*(X; \mathcal{R}) := H^*(X_G; \mathcal{R}),
$$
where $X_G := (X \times EG) / G$ is the **homotopy quotient**, $EG \to BG = EG / G$ being the universal principal bundle of the group $G$.

The natural projection
$$
X_G \to BG
$$
obtained by collapsing the elements of $X$ gives rise to a ring homomorphism
$$
H^*(BG; \mathcal{R}) \to H_G^*(X; \mathcal{R}),
$$
or equivalently to an action of the ring $H^*(BG; \mathcal{R})$ on the equivariant cohomology $H_G^*(X; \mathcal{R})$ of $X$.

Suppose now that $G$ acts freely on $X$. In this case, the cohomology groups $H_G^*(X; \mathcal{R})$ and the singular cohomology $H^*(X/G; \mathcal{R})$ of $X/G$ agree.

My question is the following: how does $H^*(BG; \mathcal{R})$ act on the singular cohomology of $X/G$ (if it can make things easier, one might take $\mathcal{R}=\mathbb{C}$)?

Comment: Since there is already an answer, this comment may be superfluous, but you can combine your first statement and your second statement to see how one gets the action.

Answer (score 1):

$EG$ is also the universal free $G$-space, meaning that, if $X$ is a free $G$-space (let's assume of the $G$-homotopy type of a $G$-CW complex), there is, up to $G$-homotopy, a unique $G$-map $X\to EG$. Taking quotients, you get a map $X/G \to BG$ which induces the action of $H^\ast(BG)$ on $H^\ast(X)$ with any coefficients.

**Edited to add:** I really should have mentioned that $X/G \to BG$ is the classifying map of the bundle $X\to X/G$. I think this makes it a little less mysterious where the map comes from.

**Second edit to add (simultaneously with Mike Miller's comment):** To give an example where the action is nontrivial, let $G = {\mathbb Z}/2$ and $X = S^n$ with $G$ acting as $-1$. Then $X/G = {\mathbb R}P^n$, $BG = {\mathbb R}P^\infty$, and $X/G \to BG$ is the inclusion. $H^\ast(BG;{\mathbb Z}) = {\mathbb Z}[x]$ then acts in the obvious, nontrivial way on $H^\ast(X/G;{\mathbb Z}) = {\mathbb Z}[x]/x^{n+1}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I’m not sure I understand. What exactly is the action? My guess is that $H^*(BG)$ acts by $0$ on $H^*(X/G)$. Is it true (or when is it true)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you’re asking. It’s the same as the action on $X_G$ under the identification you gave.

Comment: @BrianT That is certainly not true. Try an example, like $X = S^3$ with the circle action coming from the Hopf fibration. That will be true if $X \cong G \times (X/G)$ as a $G$-bundle so that the map $X/G \to BG$ is null-homotopic. There may be some bizarre non-trivial cases where all positive degree elements of the cohomology ring act as 0, but I don't know them and expect this to be very very rare.

Comment: Let's take the case of $X=EG$.  Then the action of $H^*(BG)$ on $H^*(X/G)$ is just the ring multiplication.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. In an article of A. Givental https://math.berkeley.edu/~giventh/papers/tor.pdf
in the proof proposition $6.3$ (last lines of p.46) it is stated that the coefficient algebra $H_{T^k}^*(pt)$ acts trivially (by $0$ if I understand well the equation below the statement) on singular cohomology, where $T^k$ is a torus of dimension $k$ acting on certain sublevel sets of $\mathbb{C}^n$. Does someone understand this statement?

Comment: Since the general statement is false, there must be something special about the particular spaces in question there. But 46 pages into a paper somewhat outside my expertise, I don't see what that would be. Perhaps ask Givental himself?

Comment: I would like to understand where my mistake is in the following reasoning:
the map $X/G \to BG$ is induced by passing to the quotient the composition $X \hookrightarrow X \times EG \to EG$. Therefore, intuitively, in order to take the cup product of an element of $H^*(BG; \mathbb{C})$ with an element of $H^*(X/G; \mathbb{C})$, we use the inclusion $X \hookrightarrow X \times EG$, which "forgets" the elements of $EG$. Hence, the cup product of the pull back to $H^*(X / G; \mathbb{C})$ of a class in $H^*(BG; \mathbb{C})$ with an element of $H^*(X / G)$ should be $0$. Can someone help?

Comment: If the map $X\to X\times EG$ were given by picking a $G$-fixed point in $EG$ and mapping $X$ to that point, you would be right. But it isn't: $EG$ is a free $G$-space, so has no such fixed points. It's a not-entirely trivial fact that there is, up to $G$-homotopy, a unique $G$-map $X\to EG$.